# Words that indicate the reverse of or the opposite of?

Tags: single-word-requests

is there a list of all words to indicate the reverse of something? Is there a term for such words?

**Examples**

- Un: unpopular (lack of popularity) / uninstall (to delete)
- Non: nonsense (making no sense)
- Less: senseless (making no sense)
- De: dehumanize / decrease

Edit: For clarification, I am not asking about antonyms. I am asking for portions of the words (eg. Un, Non, Less, De) that help indicate the opposite of something and whether there is a term for these words.

Thank you

Comment: Antonym:  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/antonym

Comment: @user067531 Yes, I am aware of that. But I am not referring to antonyms. I am referring to only the portions of the words that indicate the opposite (eg. Un, Non, Less, De). Are there terms for these group of words? Thanks.

Comment: There's also *in-*, but it doesn't always result in the opposite meaning: *inhumane* is the opposite of *humane*, but *inflammable* is not the opposite of *flammable*.

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you. Yes, that is what I am looking for. A list of such terms and whether there is a terminology for them so that I can search for them easily. Thank you.

Comment: ***Un-*** prefix of reversal, deprivation, or removal (as in unhand, undo, unbutton)  - https://www.etymonline.com/word/un-

Comment: @user067531 thanks for the link. So I know that I would have to search for something along the lines of prefix / suffixes of reversal, deprivation, or removal. Or something along that lines.

Comment: It appears it is just a prefix: http://www.affixes.org/u/un-.html - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/un- https://books.google.it/books?id=tjnoZ9zGSgoC&pg=PA236&lpg=PA236&dq=un-+as+a+reversal+prefix&source=bl&ots=egNqY8NMXw&sig=ACfU3U1NTjX2kVfyPaqwakTzIlSa0ZExZg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCsYbmkb_oAhUhlIsKHVmXB8cQ6AEwD3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=un-%20as%20a%20reversal%20prefix&f=false

Answer (score 2):

**Negation** (noun) is the process of making something negative (or reverse).

**[Negate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/negate)** (verb)

When you want to express the opposite meaning of a particular word or sentence, you can do it by inserting a **negation** (negating it). Negations are words like *no, not, never* etc.

**Example:** I will eat a pizza -> negation -> I will **not** eat a pizza.

It's the negation of sentences...

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

Similarly, we negate *words* by adding affixes (prefix or suffix) to them.

The common *prefixes of negation* are **ir, un, anti, il, im, dis** etc.

**Examples:** responsible -> irresponsible, comfortable -> uncomfortable, clockwise -> anti-clockwise, legal -> illegal, possible -> impossible, ability -> disability etc.

The common *suffix* that negate words is **less**.

**Examples:** hopeless, restless, homeless etc.

Here's a full explanation of [*negation*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/negation_2).

☆━━✥✥✥━━☆

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a single word for this, but there is a phrase for it:

- Negative Prefix

I cannot find a great (primary) reference for it, but a google on that will give lots of non primary source hits that match what you're looking for.

The best I can find is this:

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-language-and-linguistics/article/analogical-modeling-and-morphological-change-the-case-of-the-adjectival-negative-prefix-in-english/AB0A5610038982A5BF0B6343EEC9C94E

"AM is then tested on the case of the adjectival **negative prefix** in English (in-, un-, dis-, etc.), "

(emphasis is mine)